# Why Smart's attack doesn't work on this ECDLP?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

The Problem is as follows:

```
sage: p=235322474717419
sage: a=0
sage: b=8856682
sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [a, b])
sage: P = E(200673830421813, 57025307876612)
sage: Q = E(40345734829479, 211738132651297)
sage: P.order() == p
True
```

As we can see, P.order() is equal to p, so obviously we can use Smart's attack to calculate the value of k, so i implement the Smart's attack according to the paper [Weak Curves In Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/novotney.pdf).

And when we use this kind of attack we will get k = 9762415993955:

```
sage: SmartAttack(P,Q,p,8)
9762415993955
```

But actually the correct value of k is 152675955744921:

```
sage: P*152675955744921 == Q
True
```

So my question is:

> Why Smart's attack doesn't work on this ECDLP?

P.S. The implement of Smart's attack is correct cuz it can calculate the correct value of k in some former CTF games.

Comment: The Smart's [attack](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/97/HPL-97-128.pdf) works when the trace is 1 i.e the order of the EC group is equal to the order of the scalar ring. Here both are $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why Smart's attack doesn't work?

Comment: Is there something wrong ?If the sssa attack can't work.How did you get the correct value of k is 139189752582973.
I try sssa attack on it.And i get k is 139189752582973 rather than 165356703608039.

Comment: i use discrete_log_rho() in sagemath to get k = 139189752582973, could you please show me how  did you get the correct value of k? I implement the Smart's attack according to this paper above.

Answer (score 7):

The reason the attack does not work is because you are hitting a special case—the canonical lift. This is the case where the lifted curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is isomorphic to the curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, in which case no additional information can be extracted from it. The [journal version](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001459900052) of Smart's paper mentions this case.

The solution is simple: if we are hitting a special lift, randomize the lift! We can do this by lifting to the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ curve $y^2 = x^3 + (p\cdot a')x + (8856682 + p\cdot b')$, for some arbitrary $a'$ and $b'$, which reduces all the same modulo $p$, but will be unlikely to hit the same issue. So we can easily rewrite the attack as

```
def SmartAttack(P,Q,p):
    E = P.curve()
    Eqp = EllipticCurve(Qp(p, 2), [ ZZ(t) + randint(0,p)*p for t in E.a_invariants() ])

    P_Qps = Eqp.lift_x(ZZ(P.xy()[0]), all=True)
    for P_Qp in P_Qps:
        if GF(p)(P_Qp.xy()[1]) == P.xy()[1]:
            break

    Q_Qps = Eqp.lift_x(ZZ(Q.xy()[0]), all=True)
    for Q_Qp in Q_Qps:
        if GF(p)(Q_Qp.xy()[1]) == Q.xy()[1]:
            break

    p_times_P = p*P_Qp
    p_times_Q = p*Q_Qp

    x_P,y_P = p_times_P.xy()
    x_Q,y_Q = p_times_Q.xy()

    phi_P = -(x_P/y_P)
    phi_Q = -(x_Q/y_Q)
    k = phi_Q/phi_P
    return ZZ(k)
```

which now succeeds:

```
sage: p=235322474717419
sage: a=0
sage: b=8856682
sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [a, b])
sage: P = E(200673830421813, 57025307876612)
sage: Q = E(40345734829479, 211738132651297)
sage: assert(P.order() == p)
sage: n = SmartAttack(P, Q, p)
sage: assert(n*P == Q)
sage: n
152675955744921
```

Comment: Samuel, why is the comment above not required anymore? Is it answered with the edit? If so, how? Or do you see it as a different question?

Comment: I fixed the reason why it wasn't working. Also, these parameters are part of some Chinese challenge, so I replaced all parameters in the question and answer with random ones, to avoid the solutions being triviallly Googleable.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one method to solve efficiently the discrete logarithm on anomalous elliptic curves. One of them (in the link you gave) is to lift the curve to $p$-adic numbers. The other consist simply to add slopes of lines during computation of $pP$ et $pQ$ with any scalar multiplication algorithm. I cannot explain why the first method doesn't seem to work in this example since I am not really familiar enough with $p$-adic numbers, but I can explain the second one below with more details.

- Points on the curve are associated with one more values in $\mathbf F_p$. Example : $[P_1, \alpha_1]$, $[P_2,\alpha_2]$.
- The addition of two points needs to take care of this new value in this way with an augmented addition which we will note $\oplus$:
  $$
  [P_1, \alpha_1] \oplus [P_2, \alpha_2] = [ P_1 + P_2, \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + a_0(P_1,P_2)],
  $$
  where the function $a_0$ returns the slope of the line that goes through the two points (or $0$ if one of the points is the infinity point or if the line is vertical).
- Now we can compute $p[P,0]$ and $p[Q,0]$ with the augmented addition (a simple *double-and-add* do the work) and we get respectively $[\infty, \alpha]$ and $[\infty, \beta]$ where the values $\alpha$ and $\beta$, viewed as integers, satisfy the relation
  $$
  \beta P = \alpha Q,
  $$
  and we get the discrete logarithm by multiplying $\beta$ with the inverse mod $p$ of $\alpha$ for a total complexity $O(\log p)$.

Why it works is a little bit more complicated to explain here, but some informations can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-226/S0025-5718-99-01043-1/S0025-5718-99-01043-1.pdf) and [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00887-4/S0025-5718-98-00887-4.pdf).